# MVC Core 3.1: How to display a 360 degree viewer of a 3d image

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

How can I show a 360 degree 3D photo viewer in a MVC Core 3.1 website?

Comment: is it a photo or a 3d object?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try some of this examples using jquery

https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-360-degrees-image-display-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Three.JS lib for your view part

[ThreeJS docs](https://threejs.org/)

Here is some [open source example](https://github.com/Ahm7dKhalifa/THREE.js-With-ASP.NET-MVC) for you

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/3dweb/360javascriptviewer/lib/JavascriptViewer.min.js"></script>


    <a-scene>
        <img id="panorama" src="~/images/gear-360_overview_bg.jpg"  />
        <a-sky src="#panorama" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
```